# C# Access OleDb Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbexception, oledbparameter

Would you please kindly check the following code for errors that give me a **'Data type mismatch in criteria expression'** exception? I just can't seem to find the source of the problem...

[image]

*`record.Date` of nullable `DateTime?` type is explicitly casted to `DateTime`

*`record.Date` is set as nullable for other uses in the program. But the `record.Date` set for the *INSERT operation* is retrieved from a *DateTimePicker*, so a `record.Date` value for this method **should never be null**.

WHERE

[image]

AND (in case you're wondering)

[image]

---

From my Access file (Design View):

[image]

---

Thank you!

---

Here's the AddRecord method. Thanks!

```
public static int AddRecord(Record record)
{
    OleDbConnection connection = LABMeetingRecordsDB.GetConnection();
    string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO DocumentInfo " +
                             "([FileName], [Date], [Subject], [Type]) " +
                             "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try {
        OleDbCommand insertCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertStatement, connection);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", record.FileName);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", (DateTime)record.Date);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", record.Subject);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", record.getDBType());

        connection.Open();
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string selectStatement = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('DocumentInfo') FROM DocumentInfo";
        OleDbCommand selectCommand = new OleDbCommand(selectStatement, connection);
        int recordID = Convert.ToInt32(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());

        AddCategory(connection, recordID, record.Category);

        return recordID;

        } catch (OleDbException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is `record` in your case.. can you show that structure.. also you need to check for or Cast record.DateTime to DBNULL if it's null can you show more code declaration.. are you familiar with ` null-coalescing operator ??` so `insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", record.Date ?? DBNull.Value);` perhaps would work

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,@DJKRAZE. Edited!

Comment: you are assigning the DataTime? as Nullable

Comment: I am wondering why your are assigning Nullable types? either way I have posted a working solution that should work for you in the future when you are declaring as property as Nullable `?` use the ` null-coalescing operator`

Comment: `record.getDBType()` this is not needed because it will not return the value at all in fact I am actually thinking that it would return System.String or error can you let us know if the changes worked for you..?

Comment: Thank you,@DJKRAZE. I'm actually new to C# and the ?? operator is something new to me! But it doesn't work on (DateTime)record.Date because it is not a nullable type (i.e. already casted to DateTime). Still, I'm not sure if record.Date is the problem, and record.Date here will never be null because the DateTime value is retrieved from a DateTimePicker.

Comment: Nullabe DateTime must have a value.. so I ask again where in code are you assigning record.Date..? if I declare a variable and assign it the following `public static DateTime? Date { get; set; }` tell me what the value of `Date will be when I run past the line of code..? you are not understanding how to initialize and assign nullable variables you need to assign record.Date

Comment: On this particular form where the above INSERT operation is used, `record.Date = dtpDate.Value;`. `record.Date` is set as `DateTime?` because the nullable type is needed somewhere else, but here, since a `Record` is set with its date set using a _DateTimePicker_'s value, it should never be null.

Comment: Ok so I ask you when you are debugging it does it set the value correctly to record.Date..? and if so then there is no need to cast it as DateTime when the database should resolve the datatype

Comment: also your getDBType should be called within the method not withing the AddParameters that's kind of weird and wouldn't hurt to move it outside don't you think..

Comment: Yes, `record.Date` is correctly set here. I removed the casting but it still doesn't work. Maybe it has nothing to do with `record.Date`?

Comment: also where is the `OleDbCommand` Command type defined try adding this after you declare inserCommand
`insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;`

Comment: What does ex display.. can you show why are you not displaying ex.Message ?

Comment: The ex.Message is exactly as I posted above: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression'. But I think I found the problem now (which I'm about to post up there) :D

Comment: you have several problems but I think that what I have put for you in my answer should help get you to resolving any other issues.. also make sure the connection is still open before executing this line as well `OleDbCommand selectCommand = new OleDbCommand(selectStatement, connection);`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So...[PROBLEM SOLVED] :D

From [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217464/trying-to-insert-datetime-now-into-date-time-field-gives-data-type-mismatch-er) I learnt that

> The problem of the mismatch in criteria expression is due to the
>   OleDbType assigned to the parameter used to represent the DateTime.Now
>   value when you call AddWithValue.
>
> The OleDbType choosen by AddWithValue is DBTimeStamp, but Access wants
>   a OleDbType.Date.

Meaning that the convenient `AddWithValue` pulled a fast one on me...

Thank you @LarsTech and @DJKraze for helping me out despite the confusion of the presentation!

Comment: Yes, "AddWithValue" got me good for a few hours... I wouldn't have looked at that AddWithValue was choosing different type hadn't I seen this post.

Comment: Problem solved, yes. Also, you note the fundamentals of the problem.  But you didn't write what you actually did to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
OleDbConnection connection = LABMeetingRecordsDB.GetConnection();
string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO DocumentInfo " + "([FileName], [Date], [Subject], [Type]) " + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
OleDbCommand insertCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertStatement, connection);
insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", record.FileName);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", (DateTime)record.Date ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", record.Subject);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", record.getDBType ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
connection.Open();
try
{
  insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(OleDbException e)
{
   LogYourMessage(e.Message);
}
```

Casting the DBNull.Value as (object)DBNull.Value; is the correct way to handle the object try this I just checked on my end and did a similar test that works..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use a ToString() make your date data to the correct format which will be accepted by access

```
 insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", record.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yy"));
```